# How to show fancy header on first page?

Tags: fancyhdr

I am using fancy header, but it is suppressed on the first page. How do I get the header to show up on page 1? Below is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}  
\usepackage[margin = 1in]{geometry}    
\usepackage{amsmath}    
\usepackage{amssymb}    
\usepackage{amsthm}    
\usepackage{fancyhdr}    

\pagestyle{fancy}   
\fancyhf{}   
\rhead{\textbf{Research Statement}}    
\lhead{\textbf{John Doe}}   
\rfoot{Page \thepage}   
\begin{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
\pagestyle{fancy}   
\fancyhf{}   
\rhead{\textbf{Research Statement}}    
\lhead{\textbf{John Doe}}   
\rfoot{Page \thepage}   
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \rhead{\textbf{Research Statement}}%    
  \lhead{\textbf{John Doe}}%   
  \rfoot{Page \thepage}%  
}
```

See documentation, section 7